# comparing ArrayLists sectors through the get method

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, get

I couldn't' figure out why my code was not working, specifically it is giving me problems with the ArrayList.get(i) == ArrayList.get(i); in Java, it should return and compare the two numbers, is that not correct?

```
package homework.pkg9;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Homework9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create a method that creates a random winning lottery ticket
        //Ask the user to input his 5 numbers for the winning lottery
        //Make a mthode that campares the two arrays and return the numbers that match
        //If all numbers match generate the messge "Grand Prize Winner!"
        ArrayList userArray = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList randomArray = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList finalArray = new ArrayList();
        int userPick, counter = 0;

        randomArray = lottryNumbers();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            userPick = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose a number between 0 and 9"));

            while (userPick <= 0 || userPick >= 9) {
                userPick = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry, please choose a number between 0 and 9"));
            }

            userArray.add(userPick);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (userArray.get(i) == randomArray.get(i)) {
                counter++;
                finalArray.add(userArray.get(i));
            }
        }

        if (finalArray.size() == 5) {
            System.out.println("Grand Prize Winner!");
        }

        System.out.println("Sorry, /n you only got these " + counter
                + " numbers correct: /n" + finalArray);
    }

    public static ArrayList lottryNumbers() {
        ArrayList randomArray = new ArrayList();
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            randomArray.add(rand.nextInt(10));
        }

        return randomArray;

    }
}
```

Comment: To understand how to best use this site, take the tour and read the help center.

Comment: @EdonFreiner Must you use ArrayList? It doesn't seem appropriate for this scenario.

Comment: @EdonFreiner `array list sectors`, do you mean `array list elements?`

Answer (score 1):

In java

1. `Integer` is an object while `int` is primitive.
2. `Collections`(e.g. `ArrayList`) can only hold `Object`s and no `primitive` data

now to compare the values of two objects you must use `equals(Object o)` method (note `==` only compares the refrences)
so when you say

```
array.add(10);
```

in here 10 will be converted to an `Object Integer` then gets added to the array.

So in your case to check equality you should have something like

```
userArray.get(i).equals(randomArray.get(i)
```

Comment: I get it. thank you so much, is there a way to parse a string to an int not an integer?

Comment: @EdonFreiner in Integer class there is a method called parseInt, which converts `String` to `int`